# Trying to use Checkbox in AMPscript code to determine field value

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to use a Checkbox to determine the value based on field value from another object.  There are three outcomes, depending on Account Type (Account Object) and Checkbox (Custom Object). This is what I have written out:

```
If @AccountType = ”Regular”,”Select” AND = @Bonusweek = “False” (Checkbox) Then @Weektype equals “Standard”
If @AccountType = “Regular” AND = @Bonusweek = “True” (Checkbox)
Then @Weektype = “Bonus”
If @AccountType = “Select” AND @Bonusweek = True
Then @Weektype = “Upgrade”
```

This is the AMPscript Code I currently have but keeps throwing errors:

```
%%[IF RequestParameter("Checkbox") == "true" THEN
    SET @Bonusweek = "true"
ELSE
    SET @Bonusweek = "false"
ENDIF
]%%

%%[
Var @AccountType,@Bonusweek,@WeekType

if (@AccountType == "Regular" or "Select") AND @Bonusweek == “false” 
Then SET @WeekType = 'Standard'

ELSEIF
(@AccountType == "Regular") AND @Bonusweek == “True” 
Then SET @WeekType = 'Bonus'
ELSEIF
(@AccountType == "Select") AND @Bonusweek == “True” 
Then SET @WeekType = 'Upgrade'


ENDIF
%%=v(@WeekType)=%%
]%%
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try changing to... if (@ AccountType == "Regular" or @ AccountType == "Select") AND @ Bonusweek == “false” then...

Comment: Hi Macca, I tried that, but I am still getting the same error.   Error 1: Script IF Statement Invalid<br>An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where @AccountType's supposed to be set, but here's your code rewritten with the variable being set:

```
%%[
VAR @AccountType,@Bonusweek,@WeekType

/* This is presumably set elsewhere, somehow? */
SET @AccountType = "Regular"

IF RequestParameter("Checkbox") == "true" THEN
    SET @Bonusweek = "true"
ELSE
    SET @Bonusweek = "false"
ENDIF

IF (@AccountType == "Regular" OR @AccountType == "Select") AND @Bonusweek == "false" THEN
    SET @WeekType = 'Standard'
ELSEIF (@AccountType == "Regular") AND @Bonusweek == "true" THEN
    SET @WeekType = 'Bonus'
ELSEIF (@AccountType == "Select") AND @Bonusweek == "true" THEN
    SET @WeekType = 'Upgrade'
ENDIF
]%%
%%=v(@WeekType)=%%
```

Comment: Hi Macca, Thank you for your feedback, I ended up removing the RequestParameter section and was able to get it to work.  I appreciate your help.